# Converting an update on a large object from spread to Object.assign()

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the spread operator to update a large object and it works just fine, except it feels like allot to type each time I want to update an object

```
setGlobal((state: any) => ({
         ...state,
         locationData: {
           ...state.locationData,
           Config: { ...state.locationData.Config, Enabled: true },
         },
      }));
    }
  }, [onlineResponse]);
```

and I want to try out Object.assign() but I can't get the same result and my linter is blowing up saying I've got missing ',' and ':'

```
setGlobal((state: any) => ({
        const state = Object.assign({}, state, {state.locationData.Config.Enabled : true })
      }));
    }
  }, [onlineResponse]);
```

Comment: I would stick with the spread operator because it feels cleaner. To avoid typing a lot you may consider extracting the code into a function (but inside that function I would keep the spread operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In My opinion spread operator syntax looks cleaner and readable, but if you want to achieve same functionality with `Object.assign` then it will be like:

```
Object.assign({}, state, { locationData: { ...state.locationData, config: {...state.locationData.config, Enabled: true }} });
```